# is it possible to pass a json object with vars as an angularjs directive param?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

here is how I am trying now:

```
<ul
    class="list"
    list query="
        {
            'people': [{'people.id': '+id_+' }],
                    }
                }" 
>
   <!-- ... -->
```

on the directive I do:

```
var query = scope.$eval(attrs.query);
```

but by logging this variable I can see that the '+id_+' variable is not 'replaced' it's value.

I know there are many other ways of achieving the same resilt, but I feel like this one would be the most dynamic for at least this situation.

Comment: If `id_` comes from the `$scope` of a controller and your directive uses an isolate scope, I don't think you'll have access to the value.

Comment: Potentially {{}} will work but seeing more of the directive def would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to evaluate the the value of `_id` when you pass it in as an attribute: `{{_id}}`, see [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9rdhJzE9ORs3WCm6Anv9?p=preview). However for the sake of readability I would avoid passing in Json objects like that into a directive, place that object on your controllers scope and pass that variable to the directive.